# How to relabel nodes in a rdf(.ttl) graph in visual presentation in python?

Tags: python, graph, rdf, ttl, rdflib

I want to get a visual presentation of a rdf(.ttl) graph.
I am using this code(python):

> ```
> # print the ttl sources as a graph
> def nt_to_graph(rel_path):
>   g = Graph()
>   g.parse(rel_path, format="ttl")
>   g.bind("food", "http:<some_url>/food#")
>
>   G = rdflib_to_networkx_multidigraph(g)
>
>   # Plot Networkx instance of RDF Graph
>   pos = nx.spring_layout(G, scale=2)
>   edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "r")
>   nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels)
>   nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
>   plt.show()
> ```

The nodes have the labels as follow:
"http:some_url/food#".

I want the node label to be just "food".

How can i do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would label an RDF class like this:

```
<some_class_uri>
  a rdfs:Class ;
  rdfs:label "Some Class" ;
  ...
```

And properties and Named Individuals similarly.

The prefix you're quoting here, food: http:/food#> isn't a label but a compact URI prefix mapping. Such a prefix will allow RDF serializers like rdflib's Turtle serializer to reduce

```
<http:<some_url>/food#Something> a rdfs:Class ;
```

to

```
food:Something a rdfs:Class ;
```

But this isn't going to do anything for labels.

I suggest you create labels in your RDF as actual properties of nodes (Classes, Properties or Named Individuals) and then extract them for plugging in to networkx as needed.